# Can I jack my house briefly to replace a mud sill?

Tags: foundation, studs, load-bearing

I discovered that the mud sill by my garage exterior door has rotted about 12 inches on each side. Only about half the wood is gone and the 3” vertical support beams are resting on about 1.5” of mud sill.

I’d like to just yank out the mud sill and replace with a new 2x8. But I believe this will require jacking the support beam to properly remove the mud sill piece. Is this ok to DIY? The tutorials are pretty clear on how to do it.

Here is the rotted area. Of what was originally I think a 2x8, about half is gone in the worst spot:

[image]

And here are those same vertical beams if you’re looking upwards. You can see the vertical beams support the center of the garage extension:

[image]

Otherwise there is no sign of stress or damage. I only noticed because I was replacing old drywall from like the 70s.

Please no doomer advice on the worst case scenario, I’m looking for just the next logical step: either I can look into lifting it about 1/8” to leverage the piece out and replace it, or I’ll call a professional for a consultation .

Comment: You do have acrow jacks and the places to stand them? If the tutorials are so good what are you asking for?

Comment: Should also have supports handy and not trust the the jacks alone to hold while you are working.

Comment: @SolarMike looking for perspective. Instructions are one thing but maybe people with more experience and wisdom believe while you can sometimes jack a house for this and that, maybe this isn’t one of those cases? Good input so far otherwise.

Comment: Would be interested in knowing about the rest of the house. Is this the corner of an attached garage? Is there a second floor above? Is there a crawl space or basement underneath? And my opinion: it wouldn't cost to bring a pro out to look at it. You'd certainly learn from the conversation.

Comment: Is the garage attached to the house or by itself?  It will make a difference to the weights expected.  Will probably need more than 1/8 lift to remove enough weight.

Comment: Insert vertical steal beam, so you can remove the wooden support to access the repair area

Comment: Hire a pro. While it can be done DIY, you need a lot of jacks and when you factor in how much time you'll spend getting up to speed you'll not really be saving anything.

Comment: What is above the garage?  Is it a room, or does the garage have it's own roof over it?  This makes a difference in being able to estimate how much weight those 5 2x's are carrying.

Answer (score 3):

If all you are going to do is replace the mudsill under the right-most studs, then you'll likely be fine with supporting the door header and the sill above it for the king stud.

However there's a risk that you are dealing with a larger repair. From the picture it appears there is more going on, and you have possible stud failure, since one appears to have dropped likely due to the failed sill but also due to an inadequate nailing job.

You need to assess the damage to the other studs that hold up the 3-ply beam, and to the foundation & sill under all the studs.

This can be done while working on the doorway studs, meaning you can arrange a site visit for foundation repairs once you have the right most studs lifted and you are able to clear and inspect the foundation there.

Whether you can lift and support the load on the entire stud assembly depends on the total load (on the beam etc..) and available support/footing for lifting in that area.

If the foundation and all studs are sound, the sill replacement can maybe be done piecewise, e.g. right 3 then left 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, looks good to go to me. I'd jack that 3-piece beam up top for everything. You could also screw or nail-on a cleat to the vertical beam and further assist or backup the main jacking.

I'd definitely even double width that Mud Sill...if possible. But, I don't see any problem coming up out of the operation. Please though, do get rid of that terrible fiberglass insulation job.